# Saving Custom Field that includes Quotation marks

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have created a custom field in woocommerce that needs to be saved as 10"x10"x10". This is a measurement and needs to have the double quotation marks. I will display this in a custom tab on the product page.

Upon saving it adds escaping slashes to the output like this:
10\"x10\"x10\"

I've tried htmlspecialchars, htmlentities & esc_html functions but nothing worked.

I did use `str_replace(\\\, '', $value)` and that did achieve what i need, but pretty sure thats not what to do

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

This is how i am creating the input, on the general section of the WC product page in the admin:

```
function create_dimension_field() {
    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'overall_dims',
        'label'         => 'Overall Dimensions',
        'class'         => 'custom-field',
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'description'   => 'Enter the overall dimensions here', 
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'create_dimension_field' );


function save_dims_field( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $value = isset( $_POST['overall_dims'] ) ? $_POST['overall_dims'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'overall_dims',  sanitize_text_field( $value ));
    $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_dims_field' );
```

Comment: As far as I was aware, `update_post_meta()`, which `$product->update_meta_data()` uses internally, shouldn't require any special treatment in this regard because it uses `wp_unslash()` before saving the data. Where are you seeing the slashes? In the input field after saving? Or on the front end? Or both?

Comment: Thanks,  I am using the WooCommerce API funcitons , `update_meta_data()` (which calls `add_meta_data()`) , i checked the API docs form WC and those do not call `wp_unslash()` , i'll try wrapping `wp_unslash` around my `update_meta_data()` call and see if that works or maybe try just using `update_post_meta' Thanks, for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: Internally the WooCommerce functions use `update_post_meta()`, which calls `update_metadata()` which calls `wp_unslash()`. So you shouldn't need to do it again. You didn't answer my question about where the error is though.

Comment: sorry, i'm seeing the slashes in the input fields in the admin, and the front end. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct symbol for abbreviating feet and inches is actually "Prime" and "Double Prime" respectively.

You can read about it more [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography).

I'm not sure if this site will change the character but `′` is Prime and `″` is Double Prime. If you can't copy/paste them from there, you could copy/paste them from the link above.

The link above also lists the Alphanumeric and Unicode values which are `&prime;`and `&#8242;;` for Prime, and `&Prime;` and `&#8243;` respectively. However, I don't believe these will output properly if put them in the custom field. So, it's probably best to just copy/paste the actual character (or use the keyboard shortcut).